# After submitting a form how can I keep the page in it's current position, so users can see errors they might have made?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms

I have a form that resides at the bottom of my page. I am using Wordpress and a plugin called Gravity Forms. After I submit the form at the bottom of my home page within the footer div and errors are found it goes to the top of the page and the errors can no longer be seen. This causes an issue with usability. Can someone please tell me how to keep the page at the current position after form is submitted ? The form is using ajax to check for errors.

Comment: Is there a link where we might be able to see this in action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either return false; or e.preventDefault();

Here's a [link](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) to an article which discusses each method

Comment: Would I attach these to the submit button like onClick function ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, ensure it's after the error validation otherwise return false; will just not run anything after the return false; statement

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an older post, but just in case anyone is searching for a solution like I was... GravityForms includes a function for this exact reason. To prevent all of your forms from reloading and jumping to the top of the page, simply use the following

```
add_filter("gform_confirmation_anchor", create_function("","return true;"));
```

You can find the topic here http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_confirmation_anchor

Comment: This one worked for me but with return false instead of true.

     add_filter("gform_confirmation_anchor", create_function("","return false;"));

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: I change the ID of the form, so Javascript of Gravity form can not remove the form.

```
/* Change ID to do not allow remove after saving */
    jQuery(".gform_wrapper").each(function(){
        var self=jQuery(this);
        var form_id=self.attr("id").replace("gform_wrapper_","mygform_wrapper_");
        self.attr("id", form_id);
    });
```

Also, do something after saving:

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(event, form_id){
        //Hide loading icon
        jQuery("#gform_ajax_spinner_"+form_id).remove();
    });
```